# speakToUser not defined in eclipse

Tags: android

can anyone please tell me why speakToUser is undefined in eclipse. I could not get much help online.
I have written a class abcAccService extending AccessibilityService, taking code from developer site, I wanted to use speakToUser function. But I get undefined function in eclipse. What could be the reason for this.

Thanks

Comment: Is that a native Android function or one that you created? I'm not familiar with it but I would make sure you have proper imports and overriding if need to.

Comment: Please post the code that gives this error.

Comment: Im using the same code as given in android developer site..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is [the code](https://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/service.html#events) you are refering to:

```
// Do something nifty with this text, like speak the composed string
// back to the user.
speakToUser(eventText);
...
```

That isn't a real method.  They don't explain it clearly but this is just a theoretical method that you need to write yourself.

---

To create a `speakToUser()` method you'll need to use the [TextToSpeech](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html) class, you can follow a [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20200927153609/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/09/using-official-texttospeech-in-android.html) to help you. There is even a sample project included with the SDK, in Eclipse go to:

- `New -> Other...`
- Then `Android > Android Sample Project`
- Eventually select `TtsEngine`.